# Unable to start Mongrel (or Passenger) on Debian due to mysql2 or mysql gems

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, debian

I originally posted this at Super User, but now think it should be here instead...

I'm trying to port my RoR webapp over to a DreamHost VPS. I've upgraded the VPS --> Ruby 1.9.2 from 1.8.7 and am using Rails 3.0.1 and the mysql2 (0.2.6) gem. I'm getting the following error when trying to start mongrel:

> /usr/bin/ruby1.8: symbol lookup error: /home/USERNAME/.gems/gems/mysql2-0.2.6/lib/mysql2/mysql2.so: undefined symbol: rb_intern2

...so I tried using the mysql (2.8.1) gem instead and get the following error:

> wrong argument type Mysql (expected Struct) (TypeError)
>
> 0  /home/USERNAME/.gems/gems/activerecord-3.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql_adapter.rb     600     in `real_connect'
>
>   1   /home/USERNAME/.gems/gems/activerecord-3.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql_adapter.rb     600     in`connect'
>   2   /home/USERNAME/.gems/gems/activerecord-3.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql_adapter.rb     164     in `initialize'
>
>   3   /home/USERNAME/.gems/gems/activerecord-3.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql_adapter.rb     36  in`new'
>   4   /home/USERNAME/.gems/gems/activerecord-3.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql_adapter.rb     36  in `mysql_connection'
>
>   5   /home/USERNAME/.gems/gems/activerecord-3.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb  230     in`send'
>   6   /home/USERNAME/.gems/gems/activerecord-3.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb  230     in `new_connection'
>
>   7   /home/USERNAME/.gems/gems/activerecord-3.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb  238     in`checkout_new_connection'
>   8   /home/USERNAME/.gems/gems/activerecord-3.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb  194     in `checkout'
>
>   9   /home/USERNAME/.gems/gems/activerecord-3.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb  190     in`loop'
>   10  /home/USERNAME/.gems/gems/activerecord-3.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb  190     in `checkout'
>
>   11  /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/monitor.rb    242     in`synchronize'
>   12  /home/USERNAME/.gems/gems/activerecord-3.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb  189     in `checkout'
>
>   13  /home/USERNAME/.gems/gems/activerecord-3.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb  96  in`connection'
>   14  /home/USERNAME/.gems/gems/activerecord-3.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb  318     in `retrieve_connection'
>
>   15  /home/USERNAME/.gems/gems/activerecord-3.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb     97  in`retrieve_connection'
>   16  /home/USERNAME/.gems/gems/activerecord-3.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb     89  in `connection'
>
>   17  /home/USERNAME/.gems/gems/activerecord-3.0.1/lib/active_record/associations.rb  1804    in`create_has_and_belongs_to_many_reflection'
>   18  /home/USERNAME/.gems/gems/activerecord-3.0.1/lib/active_record/associations.rb  1411    in `has_and_belongs_to_many'
>
>   19  /home/USERNAME/.gems/gems/activerecord-3.0.1/lib/active_record/autosave_association.rb  137     in`has_and_belongs_to_many'
>   20  /home/USERNAME/portfoliofinearts.ca/farr/app/models/project.rb  3
>   21  /home/USERNAME/.gems/gems/activesupport-3.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb    239     in `require'
>
>   22  /home/USERNAME/.gems/gems/activesupport-3.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb    239     in`require'
>   23  /home/USERNAME/.gems/gems/activesupport-3.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb    227     in `load_dependency'
>
>   24  /home/USERNAME/.gems/gems/activesupport-3.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb    239     in`require'
>   25  /home/USERNAME/.gems/gems/activesupport-3.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb    346     in `require_or_load'
>
>   26  /home/USERNAME/.gems/gems/activesupport-3.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb    300     in`depend_on'
>   27  /home/USERNAME/.gems/gems/activesupport-3.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb    216     in `require_dependency'
>
>   28  /home/USERNAME/.gems/gems/railties-3.0.1/lib/rails/engine.rb    138     in`eager_load!'
>   29  /home/USERNAME/.gems/gems/railties-3.0.1/lib/rails/engine.rb    137     in `each'
>
>   30  /home/USERNAME/.gems/gems/railties-3.0.1/lib/rails/engine.rb    137     in`eager_load!'
>   31  /home/USERNAME/.gems/gems/railties-3.0.1/lib/rails/engine.rb    135     in `each'
>
>   32  /home/USERNAME/.gems/gems/railties-3.0.1/lib/rails/engine.rb    135     in`eager_load!'
>   33  /home/USERNAME/.gems/gems/railties-3.0.1/lib/rails/application.rb   108     in `eager_load!'
>
>   34  /home/USERNAME/.gems/gems/railties-3.0.1/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb  41
>
>   35  /home/USERNAME/.gems/gems/railties-3.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb     25  in`instance_exec'
>   36  /home/USERNAME/.gems/gems/railties-3.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb     25  in `run'
>
>   37  /home/USERNAME/.gems/gems/railties-3.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb     50  in`run_initializers'
>   38  /home/USERNAME/.gems/gems/railties-3.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb     49  in `each'
>
>   39  /home/USERNAME/.gems/gems/railties-3.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb     49  in`run_initializers'
>   40  /home/USERNAME/.gems/gems/railties-3.0.1/lib/rails/application.rb   134     in `initialize!'
>
>   41  /home/USERNAME/.gems/gems/railties-3.0.1/lib/rails/application.rb   77  in`send'
>   42  /home/USERNAME/.gems/gems/railties-3.0.1/lib/rails/application.rb   77  in `method_missing'
>
>   43  /home/USERNAME/mydomain.com/test_app/config/environment.rb  10
>
>   44  /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb    31  in`gem_original_require'
>   45  /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb    31  in `require'
>
>   46  config.ru   3
>
>   47  /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.2.1/lib/rack/builder.rb  46  in`instance_eval'
>   48  /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.2.1/lib/rack/builder.rb  46  in `initialize'
>
>   49  config.ru   1   in`new'
>   50  config.ru   1

I'd prefer to use mysql2, so that's the preferred solution I'm looking for, but I will certainly appreciate input on either problem.

I'm not encountering any problems such as this in my development environment (which is windows)

Comment: When happens when you try to run a bundler command like `bundle list`?

Comment: @Steven Xu - `bundle list` works. though I should add that there is a Warning : _/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/specifications/archive-tar-minitar-0.5.1.gemspec:12: invalid multibyte char (UTF-8)
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/specifications/archive-tar-minitar-0.5.1.gemspec:12: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting keyword_end
...d heavily on Mauricio Fernández's implementation in rpa-base..._ - though I will be trying the uninstall of Ruby 1.8 as mentioned below

Comment: the uninstall on Ruby 1.8 did get rid of the above warning.

Answer (score 1):

You'd mentioned that you're running Ruby 1.9.2 but your error dump looks like it's running Ruby 1.8 I'm not sure that this would cause the problem or not but it seems like a potential issue.

I'd uninstall ruby1.8 and see if it fixes anything.

`sudo apt-get remove ruby1.8`